# Substitute entries of numpy array with numpy arrays

Tags: numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

I have a numpy array A of size ((s1,...sm)) with integer entries and a dictionary D with integers as keys and numpy arrays of size ((t)) as values. I would like to evaluate the dictionary on every entry of the array A to get a new array B of size ((s1,...sm,t)).

For example

```
D={1:[0,1],2:[1,0]}
A=np.array([1,2,1])
```

The output shout be

```
array([[0,1],[1,0],[0,1]])
```

Motivation: I have an array with indexes of unit vectors as entries and I need to transform it into an array with the vectors as entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can rename your keys to be 0-indexed, you might use direct array querying on your unit vectors:

```
>>> units = np.array([D[1], D[2]])
>>> B = units[A - 1]    # -1 because 0 indexed: 1 -> 0, 2 -> 1
>>> B
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1]])
```

And similarly for any shape:

```
>>> A = np.random.random_integers(0, 1, (10, 11, 12))
>>> A.shape
(10, 11, 12)
>>> B = units[A]
>>> B.shape
(10, 11, 12, 2)
```

You can learn more about advanced indexing on the [numpy doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) to locate those row indices to index into the values of the dictionary and then simply indexing it to get the desired output, like so -

```
idx = np.searchsorted(D.keys(),A)
out = np.asarray(D.values())[idx]
```

Sample run -

```
In [45]: A
Out[45]: array([1, 2, 1])

In [46]: D
Out[46]: {1: [0, 1], 2: [1, 0]}

In [47]: idx = np.searchsorted(D.keys(),A)
    ...: out = np.asarray(D.values())[idx]
    ...: 

In [48]: out
Out[48]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> np.asarray([D[key] for key in A])
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1]])
```

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.